# Consola del navegador web no muestra Warnings ni Errores REACT

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

**Se supone que la consola debería mostrar este tipo de advertencias y errores** por ejemplo: cuando defino una constante y no se utiliza la misma debería aparecer un *Warning,* que me indica que la constante no se esta utilizando, pero no lo muestra! :/

--> *Lo que se supone que se debe de mostrar en la consola del navegador*
Capturas realizadas de un video

[image: consola del navegador funcionando normalmente]

--> *Lo que veo en mi navegador web:*

[image: consola del navegador sin funcionar normalmente]

- He restablecido la configuración por default de chrome (tanto navegador como consola)
- Los console.log() se muestran con normalidad y la página se refresca normalmente
- Lo he probado con diferentes navegadores, pero en todos sucede lo mismo
- No he cambiado ni modificado ningún modulo o configuración por defecto de React (npx create-react-app my-app)
- Tengo 2 extensiones de react instaladas en mi navegador
  (React Developer Tools y Redux DevTools)
- Tengo "react-scripts": "4.0.2"
- Tengo la versión de node v14.15.4
- Sistema operativo Windows 10 (actualizado)
- Utilizo Visual Studio Code (actualizado)
- He intentado utilizando  el modo incognito del navegador pero sigue igual

*-Sospecho que podría ser el editor o el propio React-*

--------- **NO** ES PROBLEMA DE QUE NO REFRESCA LA PAGINA--------

--> **La página refresca normalmente al modificar cualquier cosa desde el editor de textos** (Es decir, los cambios se muestran a tiempo real en el navegador web)

***--> Repito nunca me muestra este tipo de warnings ni errores***

**¿Alguna solución, sugerencia o idea de que puede estar sucediendo?**

Comment: Me pasa lo mismo, lo lograste solucionar?

Comment: Te recomiendo utilizar WSL2 y ejecutar tu proyecto desde la carpeta raíz de wsl2. Por alguna extraña razón windows no es capaz de percibir los cambios por si solo. Y si no, utilizar directamente alguna distribución linux, es decir cambiar a Linux

Comment: me pasa lo mismo, se pudo solucionar?

Answer (score 1):

El que maneja y avisa de los warnings es el `ESLint`, comprueba que en el `package.json` tienes la configuración:

```
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  }
```

Es extraño que no te muestre los warnings si el proyecto esta creado a partir de `create-react-app` y no has tocado nada de configuración.

En la consola donde arrancas el proyecto tampoco los ves? También deberian salir ahi.

Comment: Comprobado, los tengo de la misma forma que dices, que es la configuración por defecto que trae el `create-react-app`. Las advertencias si aparecer en la consola del proyecto. Gracias por ese detalle, lo había pasado por alto. En cuanto a los errores. La mayoría de estos si aparecen en consola. La verdad no se por qué sucede. En su momento tuve un problema con React (Los cambios no se reflejaban en el navegador) pero lo solucione, supongo que esto es parte de ese problema. Seguiré buscando una solución. Gracias por tu sugerencia Tasio me ha solucionado una gran parte del problema!